# How to remove the default notification hover tooltip of salesforce CRM?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I have to remove the default notification icon hover tooltip in CRM.

[salesforce CRM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkQvR.png)